# List directory with custom name applescript

Tags: applescript

I am looking for a way to display this list with a few custom tags.
Could anybody help me out? I only found this script and is very useful to me if I could alter a few parameters. However I have zero applescript experience.

I would like to have img, description and title as extra variable.
So the output would look like this: ( I will fill in title & description in later ofc. )

```
{
 "title": "",
 "gallery": [  
 {
  "img": "101.jpg",
  "title": "",
  "description": ""
  },
  {
    "img": "102.jpg",
    "title": "",
    "description": ""
  }
  ]
}
```

etc for all images in that folder

Please find the script that outputs me my content of a chosen folder as an array. which outputs now as `{"P1000443.JPG", "P1000444.JPG"}`

```
tell application "Finder"
    set file_list to name of every file of entire contents of (choose folder with prompt "Please select directory.")
end tell
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is complicated so let me get you started. Run this script, choose a file, and look at the results.

```
set aFile to choose file
tell application "Finder" to return properties of aFile
```

You will see all of the properties you can get from a file. Right now in your code you are asking only for the "name" property so you'll have to figure out what properties you want and ask for them in a similar manner as you have asked for the name. Then you'll have to convert all of that information into a nice organized list as you request... that's the difficult part. If you want something that you can't find in the properties then you'll have to figure out how to get that information in another way, for example "description".

***EDIT***: Based on your comment, I suggest you just use a repeat loop and create a string any way you want. Here's one example. You can use this technique to create the output in any format you want.

```
set file_list to {"P1000443.JPG", "P1000444.JPG"}

set outputString to ""
repeat with i from 1 to count of file_list
    set outputString to outputString & "img: " & item i of file_list & return & "title: " & return & "description: " & return & return
end repeat
return outputString
```

The output based on the way I formatted it will look like this...

```
img: P1000443.JPG
title: 
description: 

img: P1000444.JPG
title: 
description:
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for that insight. I'll have to dig deeper into that, however I might have stated my question too difficult for what i am actually looking for or i misunderstand your answer. I want to add the description data later on manually.

I am merely looking for a way to add "custom names" / "variables" before the actual output

Fe:   "img": ( actual filename ), "description": "" ( blank for later editing )

So all in all I would be very happy to know how to output something like 

    {"img":"P1000443.JPG", "img":"P1000444.JPG"}


Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I thought you were asking for much more than you mention in your comment. I added an EDIT section to my post.